# Characteristic Polynomial of an nxn matrix with 1's directly below the main diagonal and 1 in the upper right hand corner.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

So I have the $nxn$ matrix,
$$M_n = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 &  \cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

and am trying to find the characteristic polynomial. I looked at some of the easier cases ($n=2,3,4,5$) and found that the characteristic polynomial  is $(-\lambda)^n+(-1)^{n+1}=(-1)^n(\lambda^n-1)$. Since this holds for the first few cases I was going to attempt to prove by induction that it holds for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but I am struggling on how to show this. Would it be possible (or reasonable) to go about it in this way?

Comment: You can try induction, or simply expand the determinant using any of the rows.

Comment: This is an example of a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $M$ is just a permutation of the basis elements  by the action of  $(1,2,3,\ldots,n) \in S_n$. Thus $M^n = I$ and so the characteristic polynomial of $M$ divides $x^n -1$.

Since this is monic and of degree $n$, it is your characteric polynomial as you conjectured.